# create new columns from string column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I have as DataFrame with a string column

```
val df= Seq(("0003C32C-FC1D-482F-B543-3CBD7F0A0E36 0,8,1,799,300:3  0,6,1,330,300:1  2,6,1,15861:1 0,7,1,734,300:1 0,6,0,95,300:1 2,7,1,15861:1 0,8,0,134,300:3")).toDF("col_str")

+--------------------+
|             col_str|
+--------------------+
|0003C32C-FC1D-482...|
+--------------------+
```

The string column is comprised of character sequences separated by whitespace. If a character sequence starts with 0, I want to return the second number and the last number of the sequence. The second number can be any number between 0 and 8.

```
Array("8,3", "6,1", "7,1", "6,1", "7,1", "8,3")
```

I then want to transform the array of pairs into 9 columns, with the first number of the pair as the column and the second number as the value. If a number is missing, it will get a value of 0. 
For example

```
val df= Seq(("0003C32C-FC1D-482F-B543-3CBD7F0A0E36 0,8,1,799,300:3  0,6,1,330,300:1  2,6,1,15861:1 0,7,1,734,300:1 0,6,0,95,300:1 2,7,1,15861:1 0,8,0,134,300:1")).).toDF("col_str", "col0", "col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7", "col8")

+--------------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|             col_str|col0|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7|col8|
+--------------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|0003C32C-FC1D-482...|   0|   0|   0|   0|   0|   0|   1|   1|   3|
+--------------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

I don't care if the solution is in either scala or python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following (commented for clarity)

```
//string defining
val str = """0003C32C-FC1D-482F-B543-3CBD7F0A0E36 0,8,1,799,300:3  0,6,1,330,300:1  2,6,1,15861:1 0,7,1,734,300:1 0,6,0,95,300:1 2,7,1,15861:1 0,8,0,134,300:3"""
//string splitting with space
val splittedStr = str.split(" ")
//parsing the splitted string to get the desired format with the second element as key and the last element as value of the elements starting with 0
val parsedStr = List(("col_str"->splittedStr.head)) ++ splittedStr.tail.filter(_.startsWith("0")).map(value => {val splittedValue = value.split("[,:]"); ("col"+splittedValue(1)->splittedValue.last)}) toMap
//expected header names
val expectedHeader = Seq("col_str", "col0", "col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7", "col8")
//populating 0 for the missing header names in the parsed string in above step
val missedHeaderWithValue = expectedHeader.diff(parsedStr.keys.toSeq).map((_->"0")).toMap
//combining both the maps
val expectedKeyValues = parsedStr ++ missedHeaderWithValue
//converting to a dataframe
Seq(expectedDF(expectedKeyValues(expectedHeader(0)), expectedKeyValues(expectedHeader(1)), expectedKeyValues(expectedHeader(2)), expectedKeyValues(expectedHeader(3)), expectedKeyValues(expectedHeader(4)), expectedKeyValues(expectedHeader(5)), expectedKeyValues(expectedHeader(6)), expectedKeyValues(expectedHeader(7)), expectedKeyValues(expectedHeader(8)), expectedKeyValues(expectedHeader(9))))
  .toDF()
  .show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+------------------------------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|col_str                             |col0|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7|col8|
+------------------------------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|0003C32C-FC1D-482F-B543-3CBD7F0A0E36|0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |0   |1   |1   |3   |
+------------------------------------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

and of course you would need `expectedDF` `case class` defined somewhere out of scope

```
case class expectedDF(col_str: String, col0: String, col1: String, col2: String, col3: String, col4: String, col5: String, col6: String, col7: String, col8: String)
```